# How can I manage the system tray icons?

Tags: windows-7, icons, notification-area

Windows hides all my icons. But I want to see some permanently. How can I pick myself what to hide? I need to pad my question with quality filler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the left hand side of the system tray there is a small arrow. Click the arrow, then click "Customize". From here, you can set specific icons to `Show icon and notifications`, which will show this icon permanently as long as the application driving the icon is running. Alternatively, you can choose to `Hide icon and notifications` or `Only show notiifications`.

You can also enable all icons to show, regardless of notification status, by checking the `Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar` button on the lower left hand side of this window.

A secondary way to bring up this window is to go to `Start -> Control Panel -> Notification Area Icons`

Answer (score 5):

On the left side you'll notice a small arrow. Click it. It'll open a small popup with all available(active) icons. Just drag and drop the icons to the position where you want them.

More info/pictures here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975785

Comment: You really should transfer the content from the website into your question, so when the link no longer works, your answer is still valid.